# Best way to handle several methods inside a class?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am making a server in C# and I have a singleton that handles all the logged in users in an array. That array is an array of a class called UserSession.

This UserSession class has a method that runs on a separate thread that handles the incoming packets of that user.

Well, consider this code:

```
class UserSession
{
    public UserSession(TcpClient client)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleComm);
        thread.Start((object)client);
    }

    public void HandleComm(object tcpClient)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)tcpClient;
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        while(1 == 1)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            int testShort = Convert.ToInt32(buffer);
            switch((ActionEnum)testShort)
            {
                case ActionEnum.Something:
                    // here is my problem!
                    // do some more parsing of the message
                    this.DoSomething(SomethingStruct argument); // argument taken from the byte array
                    break;
                case ActionEnum.AnotherSomething:
                    // the same as before
                    break;
                // and this goes on and on
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to handle all those separate enums without recurring to more than 80 methods on that class? (ActionEnum is an enum with the specific action of the current user).

I serialize that buffer, I just made that code fast for you to have an idea.

Comment: How come your class `UserSession` is Singleton ? it has a public constructor

Comment: I hope you handle whatever stream.Read() returns in your production code. As for the question, what's the problem with having lots of methods? If you do just several lines of code, the handling could stay inside the case itself; otherwise it probably deserves a method. upd: If your objects are serialized uniformly, it might be actually one method with some description of format of incoming message as an argument.

Comment: @Habib.OSU I have an array of UserSession inside of a class called LoggedUsers, which is a singleton

Comment: @Eugene Ryabtsev I have SEVERAL structs depending on the ActionEnum. My question was what would be the best way to manage my code so it is properly done and not a mess of more than 200 methods to handle each thing separately. Also yes, I handle everything in my class. That was just a fast sketch to show you the huge switch

Comment: .NET serializer is uniform and uses the reflection, so it could live with a stream and a typeof(struct), returning that struct. You could replicate it, depending on how exactly things are serialized. I understand it the serialization format is outside your control, or this whole thing would look strange.

Comment: If the code to process `ActionEnum.AnotherSomething` is the same as `ActionEnum.Somthing`, what's the problem then? You can just use the same code, without a switch/case block.Or, is there any code you missed? Put the code to process `ActionEnum.AnotherSomthing` will be helped.

Comment: You should replace `while (1 == 1)` with either `while (true)` or `for (;;)` (and, IMHO, put a space between `while` or `switch` (or `for` or `if`) and the following open parenthesis).

Answer (score 2):

So: What you are basically trying to do it so convert a numeric code to an invocation of a method.

There are some things you can't get, such as having this conversion done for you automatically. If you had instead transmitted names of methods, you could have used reflection to look up the method, then invoke it. Therefore you must do some manual work to establish the mapping.

What you have to decide on then is the best way to map the numbers to the methods.

One way is the one you are using now. Here the mapping is happening inside the dispatch cycle (fetch number, translate, invoke). The problem is that the mapping code obscures the dispatch code. There is also a fair amount of boilerplate code involved.

You could use a combination of Command pattern and a hash map like this:

During setup:

1. Create a common interface for your commands (or use a Closure, since
   you are using C#)
2. Create an instance of object that implements the interface pr. method you want to map
3. Add it to the hashmap.

In dispatch loop:

1. Fetch number
2. Look up number in hash table
3. If found, invoke mapped object, else failure

For a more flexible approach, consider the number as a message that has to be handled, and use pattern Chain of Responsibility.

Command pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Chain of Responsibility http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: This is what I would do. Have a map that maps enum values to methods and look them up and call them.

Comment: It's also my go-to solution for this situation. It separates the concerns nicely, and promotes use of Command pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are, as always, a lot of possible answers.   I ran into this problem when I was building my client/server game.  I started out with a few dozen Enums for actions/events/messages,  then realized it was not very sustainable when you get into larger numbers of actions.

So here's what I did, roughly, in pseudo code.

```
    NetworkClass 
    {
       RegisterChannel(objUsingChannel,typeOfChannel, callbackForChannel, expectedReturnType){/*...*/};

       PushChannelMsg(channelID, dataToSend)

       ReceiveMessageFromNetwork(msg){  Read data from network, which also contains channelID, and send it to any matching channelID}  
       //If there is no channel registered for a data that is received,  just ignore it
    }

EnemyTurretObject
{
   //Register the rotation channel and listen for rotation changes
   NetworkClass.RegisterChannel(this, channels.TurretRotated + this.ID, callback=HandleTurretRotated, doubleReturnType)

   HandleTurretRotated(double rot)
   {  rotate the turret  }
}

FriendlyTurretObject
{
   //Register two channels that we'll send data across
   NetworkClass.RegisterChannel(this, channels.TurretFired + this.ID, callback=null, MissleFiredData)
   NetworkClass.RegisterChannel(this, channels.TurretRotated + this.ID, callback=null, doubleDataType)

   FireMissle()
    {
       NetworkClass.PushChannelMsg(channels.TurretFired + this.ID, new MissleFiredData(x,y)) 
    }

    RotateTurret()
    {
      NetworkClass.PushChannelMsg(channels.TurretRotated + this.ID, newTurretRotationValue) 
    }

}
```

I basically avoided the whole huge mass of Enums,  and made a more generalized setup so that each object is responsible for it's own data, channels and such.   It's  far more flexible approach, and changing one enum doesn't break everything.  The network class doesn't even need to know what is in the data being sent, it's just a conduit now.

Comment: How would you do when you receive a packet from the user? Lets say you have different kind of actions, like "connecting" or  "disconnecting". Do you have a lot of different connections altogether?

Comment: The connecting and disconnecting is handled more specifically.  Those types of cases don't have to be inside this message passing system I described above.  And yes,  I can support hundreds of connections.   When receiving a message,  I basically read out the ChannelID,  then I look to see what kind of data that channel is expecting,  and then read the payload into a new instance of expected return type

Comment: Moving to this approach would require quite a lot of refactoring/re-writing of your net code. However, I can say that the value I gained when changing my code over has been huge.  It's extremely easy to add new actions/types/events now,  the overall net code has been cut at LEAST in half, and the simplicity makes it far easier to debug and manage